# PostMessage to nested iframe of the same domain - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Will it be possible to send postMessage to a nested iframe ?

I have parent page [ http://localhost:8765/home.html ], I have declared postMessage function in the parent page as below snippet

```
// home.html [http://localhost:8765/homr.html]
<html>
<script>
    function test1(){
        document.getElementById('tableauFrame').contentWindow.postMessage("success", "*")
    }
</script>
<body>
    child ui <br>
    <iframe width='2000px' height='2000px' src='http://localhost:8766/child.html' id='tableauFrame' onload=test1()></iframe> 
</body>
</html>
```

Inside parent page, it will call another browser to an iframe , in child browser it has another iframe which is calling page2.

```
//child.html [ http://localhost:8766/child.html ]
<html>
    <body>
        <p>Child page</p>
        <iframe src='http://localhost:8766/page2.html' id='secondary'></iframe> 
    </body>
</html>
```

if it was just a single iframe [ parent (home.html) to child(child.html)] , it will work and receive the message , but when I tried a nested iframe
parent(home.html) to grandchild[page2.html] element, it is not receiving the postMessage.

```
// grandchild [ http://localhost:8766/page2.html ]
<html>
    <script>
        window.addEventListener('message',function(message){
            if (event.origin === "http://localhost:8765") {
                console.log("displaying message from parent page : " + message.origin)
            }
        })
    </script>
    <body>
        <p>this is getting from 3rd page</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Does postMessage only work on a single frame ?

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The last part you mentioned perhaps is the most important part of code you should definitely show. Please show your code that try to postMessage to grandchild.

Comment: @RickyMo i have reedited the question

Comment: You are still not showing where you call `postMessage` on the grandchild.

Comment: I have declared postMessage in home.html , the objective im trying to achieve is to send from home.html directly to page2.html without sending postMessage on child.html

Comment: You only called `postMessage` on the first child, not calling on the grandchild. If you want to post to the grandchild, you should get a reference of the window of the grandchild and call `postMessage` on it.

Comment: @RickyMo , i have found the solution, the reason why im not referencing to child.html as my actual usecase, i only have control over grandchild, Child and grandchild is having the same domain. as for parent.html , its having a different domain. Using the solution given by connorDeckers on option 1, im able to retrieve the postMessage declared in parent page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Window messages don't "bubble down"; you can either:

1. In the grandchild page, listen to something on `window.parent` or even `window.top`, and handle all message posting on the topmost window; or
2. In the uppermost page, nest down twice:
   `document.getElementById('tableauFrame').contentDocument.querySelector('iframe').contentWindow.postMessage("success", "*")`

Comment: Great, this what im looking for option 1,
Option 2 is ideal if i have control in child.html but for my usecase, im only able to add script into grandchild.html. Thanks!